# How to reformat elements in an array on output?

Tags: perl, reformat

Using Perl, I have to read in comma separated data which is in the format

zipcode, number of cities within zip, list of each city within a zipcode. This is really working with vanity cities so that we get a list of all cities that use a zipcode.

When I write this out I need to have something like

```
{zipcode,"number of cities,list of cities"}
```

Using the chomp into an array it will put zipcode into array[0], number in array[0] and then one element for each city named in the list.  There could be 1 city or 70 cities in he list. How do I go from that array into the format that I need.  Essentially I'm taking a input file that was created from a Big Data platform and formatting it into a C# program that gets used as a plug-in to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $zipcodes = { 33401 => ['West Palm Beach','Green Acres'] }; #initial entries
push($zipcodes->{33401}, 'Jupiter'); #or add entries by pushing them into the array
print '{33401,"' . @{$zipcodes->{33401}} . ',' . join(',',@{$zipcodes->{33401}}) . "\"}\n";

#prints {33401,"3,West Palm Beach,Green Acres,Jupiter"}
```

Comment: I am reading this data in from an external csv file. I won't know what the values are and the length each lines cities are only known by a counter in the csv file. It is formated as zipcode,cntr,city1 city2 city3...etc based on the value of cntr.

Comment: That is an exercise left to the user and essentially a whole other project/question. You will need to iterate over your excel file columns/rows and stuff those variables into a data structure (such as the one provided above).